# Set LinearLayout weight in code rather than xml problem

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have the following code to try and set the weight of a linearLayout to 0.7, after looking at the documentation and some examples online it says it takes 3 parameters but in my code it will not let me:

```
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this); 
linear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So here it sets both the height and the width but the last parameter it says in the documentation is the weight and it wont let me put it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the layoutparams for linearlayout:

```
linear.setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   
                                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                      1)
);
```

As a proof-of-concept: this works. check out the import and compare them with your own :)

file: Test.java

```
package com.huiges.stackOverFlow.examples

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Test extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this); 
        linear.setLayoutParams(
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   
                                              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                              1)
        );


    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried that already, that's what I mean by it not taking 3 parameters. eclipse just wants me to remove the 1. Which is why it's confusing me.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct packages? Check your imports if neccesairy. I've seen what you mean, but this code is being parsed OK in my eclipse. I'll add a complete class if you wish?

Comment: import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

That's the only import I have relating to LayoutParams, i'm guessing that's enough though and obviously I have the LinearLayout package in there too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i'm not sure the problem was but I wrote this code in a method lower down the class as the LinearLayout is a global variable and it has worked how I wanted it too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

```
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this); 
linear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter takes a float. `0.7` is a double, use `0.7f` instead to get a float.

```
linear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                        0.7f));
```

Comment: The problem @samRowley had was that only 2 parameters where accepted, so this will not help I presume.

Comment: From the question I read that he wants to  create the LayoutParams with three parameters, one of them (the weight) having the value 0.7 but was not able to. This is exactly what happens if you forget the 'f' and have the number interpreted as a double. If he uses 0.7f the code works. Seems helpful to me :)