# How to change the weight size of a fragment in android?

Tags: java, android

Here is the xml-Layout of my fragment view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
     >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="70"

        class="com.pack.Menufragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bodyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        class="com.pack.BodyFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to change the fragment weight size from the java not from XML, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I should put the Fragments in a seperate LinearLayout and change that weight.

Like:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="70"

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        class="com.pack.Menufragment" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bodyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.pack.BodyFragment" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

In Java

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = layout1.getLayoutParam();
par.weight = NEW value;
```

Comment: I did this, but its not showing any error but not taking effect in the size either

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648962/1089811).
You can use this if you enclose each of your fragments in FrameLayouts and then set the weights for each of these frame layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at how its done for a RelativeLayout in this thread: 
[Android - How do I specify weight programmatically for a RelativeLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073346/android-how-do-i-specify-weight-programmatically-for-a-relativelayout)
Should be similar with layout params for a fragment I assume, haven't tried it so I'm not giving you any guarantees as to if this will work or not.